# Настройка Associated Domains в xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, objective-c

Подскажите пожалуйста, пытаюсь настроить Associated Domains для branch.io и не могу его найти в проекте. Пишут что должен быть по маршруту "Xcode → Project → Capabilities → Associated Domains", но его там нет, есть другие вроде HealthKit, HomeKit и т.д. Может ли это быть связано с тем что нет проплаченного аккаунта разработчика или причина другая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого нужна платная подписка